# 403 when I run most reports as super admin

Tags: civireport, permissions, reports

I have a problem with my civiCRM installation where I am now unable to run most reports. As super admin I can browse to the report config page where I can select what I display and set filters etc. I then hit the "refresh report: button and get a 403.

I do still have a couple of reports working on my dashboard, but others that don't work there (I get a message on the dashboard that I have tried to access a report that does not exist).

I'm perplexed my this.I can't find any sort of file permissions on the server that could be the problem or any permissions in drupal or civicrm that could be the issue. Maybe I'm not looking in the right spot though...

I don't think there are any other users that can run these reports either.

Comment: Are you on CiviCRM 5.2.1 (latest at the moment) 

Are the reports definitely ones that ship with core or might you have an extension providing some of them?